# SharedResourceDiationary not loaded in WPF Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I'm trying to implement the SharedResourceDictionary from here:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html

But I can't manage to let the Designer show the correct styles. (not using Blend here)

I reduced the implementation to the lowest.

```
public SharedResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary {

}
```

works fine.

```
public SharedResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary {

    public new Uri Source {
        get { return base.Source; }
        set { base.Source = value; }
    }

}
```

doesn't and the styles are not applied.

Anyone experienced this issue and aware of a working solution?

**Further explanation:**

The SharedResourceDictionary is defined in a project, which is referenced in an UserControl, where I exchanged all ResourceDictionaries with this implementation.

In this sample case I have a style which is applied to all comboboxes (without key).

The only thing I'm doing till now, is wrapping the ResourceDictionary's Source property as shown above. No further logic. Without wrapping, everything works fine, but wrapping seems to break things..

Comment: Have you added the SharedResourceDictionary in you app xaml file?

Comment: I've created a sample project with provided implementation and it works fine in both cases. So we're going to need some more information, especially 1) is your class defined in the same project and if not, 1a) what kind of project is it; 2) where and how do you reference this class (in a window/control, in the App.xaml, etc.); 3) does it break for all styles, or for specific ones (implicit, keyed, targeting framework controls and/or your custom controls).

Comment: Any luck with this? I am running in to a similar issue.